# Highchart series to take % of the chart graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[current image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/romPe.png)

What I am trying to achieve is for the series to take up 70% of the chart when the navigator is to the right (e.g. we are seeing the latest series).

I am currently using:

```
afterSetExtremes: function (e) {
    var extrX = series.xAxis.getExtremes();
    if (e.trigger=="rangeSelectorButton" || e.trigger=="navigator")
    {
        viewSpanMax = (extrX.max);
        viewSpanMin = (extrX.min);
        viewSpanDelta = viewSpanMax-viewSpanMin;
    }
    else if (series.points[series.points.length-1].x==e.max)
    {
        viewSpanMin += series.points[series.points.length-1].x-viewSpanMax;
        viewSpanMax = series.points[series.points.length-1].x;
        viewSpanDelta = (viewSpanMax-viewSpanMin)*1.3;
    }
    series.xAxis.setExtremes(Math.max(viewSpanMin,extrX.min),viewSpanMin+viewSpanDelta, false, false);
}
```

The implementation is very buggy and I was wondering whether there are working examples of highchart graphs where the series are only partially displayed (with future times still visible).

Comment: How about just increasing the `maxPadding`? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.maxPadding

Comment: Unfortunately maxPadding is lost when the zoom is set, e.g. when navigator is dragged, but it can be restored in this way: https://jsfiddle.net/1nav8dwn/2/
Also you can set max for the navigator https://jsfiddle.net/1nav8dwn/3/